# Intercept Spring Cloud Stream destination binding to modify producer properties on the fly

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am trying to find a way to intercept Spring Cloud Stream 3.1.1 destination binding in order to modify some properties on the fly in my application. I have come to the following code snippet, but it seems it only works for a dynamic binding whereas in my case channels are defined specifically and no dynamic destination has been used, so I'm not sure what I am missing here.

```
  @Bean
  public NewDestinationBindingCallback<KafkaProducerProperties> bindingConfigurer() {
    return ((channelName, channel, producerProperties, extendedProducerProperties) -> {
      if ("foo".equals(channelName)) {
        producerProperties.setUseNativeEncoding(producerUseNativeEncoding);
        producerProperties.setPartitionCount(producerPartitionCount);
      }
    });
  }
```